# Get Next 5 Lines After Where-Object

Tags: powershell

I am using the following powershell to search for a line item in a file, and select the next 5 lines that succeed the match:

```
Get-Content -Path C:\test\file.txt | Where-Object  {$_ -match "###"} | Select-Object -Last 5
```

This only returns the first line of each match. The expected result would be the first line, and the 5 that follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7) is a good candidate for this due to the `-Context` parameter:

```
Select-String -Path C:\test\file.txt -Pattern '###' -Context 0,5 |
    Foreach-Object { $_.Line,$_.Context.PostContext}
```

The `-Context` parameter takes two values. The first is the number of lines before the match. The second is the number of lines after the match. You can technically use `-Context 5` in this case because one single number applies to lines after the match.

Since `Select-String` returns a `MatchInfo` object. You will need to access the `Line` property to display the line that contains the current match. The `Context` property is a `MatchInfoContext` object that contains `Precontext` and `Postcontext` properties. Those properties contain the lines before and after the match, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-Content -Path C:\temp\file.txt | Where-Object  {$_ -match "###"} | Select-Object -Index 0,4
```

This gives you the 1st and the 5th row as a result